# Set -Wall on by default in gcc/g++

Tags: gcc, g++

While testing code posted on SO, it's very helpful to turn the `-Wall` option on. I was able to do so by creating a `Makefile` whose contents are:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall
CXXLAGS=-Wall
```

I understand that one can use

```
make CFLAGS=-Wall <target>
make CXXFLAGS=-Wall <target>
```

as well.

Is this, setting `CFLAGS/CXXFLAGS`, the only way to turn compiler flags on by default?

Is there any configuration file(s) where one can enable/disable any of the compiler options?

Comment: You can create a shell file with name gcc in path containing line `/path/to/gcc -Wall $@`.

Comment: `gcc` reads instructions from a file called `specs`. You can use `-dumpspecs` to see the builtin version and use `strace` to find out where gcc is looking for it.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I read another SO post on an unrelated topic but it suggested the same idea. I'll investigate it further and see how to make use of this information.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running bash

```
export CFLAGS="-Wall"
```

in your .bashrc is also a good place to set defaults. On BSD (Mac OSX) /etc/make.conf can be used to set default flags if you always use make. Or you can alias 'gcc' to 'gcc -Wall'. One of these should be the one you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but that is another way of setting `CFLAGS`.